# Pitest report-aggregate goal complains about transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, junit5, mutation-testing, pitest, maven-module

I integrated Pitest according to https://pitest.org/aggregating_tests_across_modules/ in a Maven module project (Maven version 3.5.4).

When running `mvn clean package` the log shows the Pitest execution for the target modules (i.e. the modules for which Pitest should be executed) and I confirmed that result files are actually produced.

However, I get the following error message for the report module:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.5.1:report-aggregate (put-it-together) on project mutationtesting:
An error has occurred in PIT Test Report report generation.:
.../.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.10.0/jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar is not a directory
```

`jackson-databind` is a dependency of the target modules and therefore a transitive dependency of the reporting module. It seems to me that the `report-aggregate` goal also tries to analyse the transitive dependencies of the modules for which Pitest is enabled.

Is there some error in the project configuration? Is this a known bug? What can I do?

I tried to change the scope of the target modules in the reporting module to provided, and I also set the packing of the reporting module to pom, but to no avail.

**Configuration**

I configured Pitest in the parent POM as follows:

```
        <properties>
            ...
            <pitest.version>1.5.1</pitest.version>
            <pitest.junit5.version>0.12</pitest.junit5.version>
        <properties>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>${pitest.version}</version>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>mutationCoverage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                    <configuration>
                        <exportLineCoverage>true</exportLineCoverage>
                        <outputFormats>
                            <value>XML</value>
                        </outputFormats>
                        <timestampedReports>false</timestampedReports>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                            <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${pitest.junit5.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
```

The target module POM's each contain this section:

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And finally the reporting module POM looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
         ...
    </parent>

    <artifactId>mutationtesting</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            target module 1
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            target module 2
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
                <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>put-it-together</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but in my case it's not even an external transitive dependency that is being complained about - it's one of the submodules that is being mutation tested and that is a dependency of another. I can include the dependency module in the aggrate report with no issues, but including the module that depends on it throws this "jar is not a directory" failure

Comment: https://github.com/hcoles/pitest/issues/621 seems relevant